How can we properly log out from an OpenID Connect (OIDC) session? Users are able to log in automatically without re-entering credentials
We're trying to log out from our OpenID Connect (OIDC) session, but the browser's saved session is allowing users to log in automatically without needing to enter their credentials. We need to ensure that the logout process effectively clears the session so that users are required to authenticate each time they log in.
We're trying to clear cookies, local storage, and app data to fully terminate the session.
We did this for authorization:
          private fun loginWithOHId() {
        val serviceConfig=AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(Uri.parse(authorizationEndpoint), Uri.parse(tokenEndpoint)) 
authState=AuthState(serviceConfig)
     val authRequestBuilder=AuthorizationRequest.Builder(serviceConfig, Client_id, ResponseTypeValues.CODE, MY_REDIRECT_URI)
     val authRequest=authRequestBuilder.setScope("OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile, OIDScopeEmail, openid").build()
     doAuthorization(authRequest)
    }
   

     private fun doAuthorization(authRequest: AuthorizationRequest) {
                val authService=this.context?.let {
                    AuthorizationService(it)
                }
            
                val authIntent=authService?.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(authRequest)
 startForResult.launch(authIntent)
            }

private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val intent = result.data
                val authService = this.context?.let { AuthorizationService(it) }
                val resp = intent?.let { AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(it) }

                val ex = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(intent)
                authState?.update(resp, ex)
                val clientAuth: ClientAuthentication =
                    ClientSecretBasic(RESTConstants.getAppAuthClientSecret())

                resp?.createTokenExchangeRequest()?.let { tokenRequest ->
                    authService?.performTokenRequest(
                        tokenRequest, clientAuth
                    ) { resp, _ ->
                        if (resp != null) {
                            authState?.update(resp, ex)
                            authState?.lastTokenResponse?.let { tokenResponse ->
                                tokenResponse.idToken?.let { token ->
                                    JWTUtils().decoded(token)?.let { subResponse ->
                                        subResponse.sub?.let { sub ->
                                            if (context?.let { it1 -> isConnected(it1) } == false) {
                                                context?.let { it1 -> NetworkUtils(it1).onNoInternetConnection() }

                                            } else {
                                                //sign in code.
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            // exchange succeeded
                        } else {
                            toast("Authorization failed")
                            // authorization failed, check ex for more details
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

